# How to refer json field from within object itself

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx

I want to separate stateless view components to a single file, while having as short code as possible.

So I have some View.js, with:

```
export default {
    MySpan: (a)=>(<span>a.someValue</span>),
    MyDoubleSpan: (a,b)=>(<div><MySpan someValue={a} /><MySpan someValue={b} /><div/>)
}
```

And inside `App.js` is something like:

```
import View from './View';
...
render() {
    return(<View.MyDoubleSpan a="a" b="b"/>);
}
```

You may intuitively get, what I expect. But (of course) this would not work. How to get out of this typical situation? Or How could I refer to some (defined) fields of a currently defining object, right from within another fields of that object?

Comment: does it change anything if you change the order of MySpan and MyDoubleSpan?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get an answer on my own! It is in defining component prior exporting, and refering to it by a name:

```
const View = {
    MySpan: (a)=>(<span>a.someValue</span>),
    MyDoubleSpan: (a,b)=>(
    <div>
        <View.MySpan someValue={a} />
        <View.MySpan someValue={b} />
    <div/>)
};
export default View;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a component that returns an array of spans (you can do that in react). This way, the amount of spans returned will be the same as the length of the array passed as props. Neat?

```
const SpanComponent = ({content:['a','b']}) => content.map(item=><MySpan someValue={item} />
```

Comment: That is not about array mapping. consider, that I need span, then div.. First of all  `SpanComponent` must be inside json object that you `export default {MySpan:() SpanComponent: ??? }` Second It would give you an error MySpan is not defined under such circumstances. That was the question - how to refer defined object field from within that object definition?

Comment: Ok. It seems you found an answer!